# Rally schema modifications

Tags: schema, rally

Is it possible to add new object types to the Rally data schema?

We are migrating to Rally from a heavily-modified Bugzilla installation, and will need to add many fields as well as some extra metadata such as versions/branches data. 
So far I found the following entry in the docs:
[Create and Customize Fields](http://developer.rallydev.com/create-custom-fields)

However, for external data like the versions data this doesn't provide a solution. Is there need some way of creating an external data repository, the like of an SQL DB table?

Thanks,
Yaron Yogev
IT Software developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom fields can be created on existing object types, but it is not possible to create new object types in Rally. The only exception is PorfolioItem type. It is possible to create custom PortfolioItem types. Rally's standard PI types are Theme, Initiative and Feature. New custom types can be created and existing ones can be renamed. See [Portfolio Item Type Field](https://help.rallydev.com/portfolio-admin#type).